# Reading Properties of a Nested Object Passed as a Property in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm passing state as props via Context to other components in my React app:

```html
state = { user: null, username: null }
```

Both username and user are updated using setState methods.

I can read the username property, but I cannot read the user property, which is supposed to be a nested object.
[image]
Please see the photos: if I pass the entire user object, I get an error saying that there are object keys, but if I try to read one of the object properties, it throws another error saying that the property is null.
[image]

This doesn't make any sense because I can check the state of the Context Provider and the nested object's values are all there:

[image]

Could any please help with this - I'm totally confused.

Comment: Can you show code in `createContext` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I was able to achieve what I was trying to do:

```js
{ user && user.username }
```

This does not throw an error and allows me to access the nested properties of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether `user` is not null, because if `user` is `null`, it will call `null.username` which will throw error. `setState()` is asynchronous, that's why the value can be null which is the initial value that you set.

```
{
user &&
  <div className='div-player'>
   ...
   ...
  </div>
}
```